# determine number of instances of a category in R

Tags: r

This is my first time experimenting with R. I currently have a dataset called mydata that includes various categories. I need to somehow determine the number of ports that are equal to 80,443,25,993 out of all of the ports.

![image: This is what my data set looks like]

Answer (score 0):

When posting a question here it's always helpful to have a sample of the data you're using. You can do this easily with `dput(head(data_frame))`. Since you didn't provide that I can demonstrate counting for a given condition with the built-in demo data frame called `mtcars`. Here is how you'd count the number of observations (i.e., rows) with a `cyl` value of 4 or 6:

```
sum(mtcars$cyl %in% c(4, 6))
```

This works because `mtcars$cyl %in% c(4, 6)` returns a vector of logical values for each observation. The vector contains `TRUE` values for the matches (i.e., where the `cyl` variable contains either a 4 or a 6) and `FALSE` values otherwise.

```
mtcars$cyl %in% c(4, 6)
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[29] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Since R treats `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as zero you can sum these values to find a total count.